# rpmbuild error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I am building a custom rpm to install apache, among other things.  When i try and build i get the above error, and then it lists /httpd-2.2.17/ and all of its subfiles.

As far as i know, this is the build directory so it shouldn't be packaged.  To try and fix this i added rm -rf /httpd-2.2.17 but that doesn't seem to help.

I don't want to add it to the %files section because they shouldn't be installed on the system when we are done.

Does anybody know what i am doing wrong?

Of note is that apache is the second source file, the first one is a tar file that doesn't get compiled

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That sounds like it should not be there..I am not familiar with the Apache build process, but I would check the build flags (what is passed to configure or similar, maybe a prefix has gone awry?).

Or, try adding an:

```
%exclude %{buildroot}/.../httpd-2.2.7
```

To the files section as a work around.

And finally, and you probably already did this, check what other RPM-based distributions do, I imagine Apache is not a trivial package..

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just an 'rm -rf /httpd-2.2.7', try 'rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/httpd-2.2.7' near the end of the %install section of the spec file.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora_Draft_Documentation/0.1/html/RPM_Guide/ch09s05s07.html

You can disable the Fascist build and it will just give you a package regardless of your extra files. Depends on how concerned you are about a clean package build.